# Is there a way to create a new object for form1 after closing a form2?

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

I'm working on a Agenda using windows forms C#, I'm trying to create a colored picture box for each appointment object in the project. Using this code that is used in a loop for each object in my appointment list im creating each picturebox on the right location on the form1 screen.

```
PictureBox Point = new PictureBox();
this.Controls.Add(Point);
Point.Location = new Point(obj.Location.X, 45 + obj.Location.Y);
Point.BackColor = color;
Point.Size = new Size(96, 25);
Point.Enabled = false;
Point.Tag = "Point";
Point.TabIndex = 100;
Point.Visible = true;
```

When I'm calling this method from input on the same form, for example a button click. It will work just fine and create all the picture boxxes as needed. But when I'm calling it from the form2.closed event it wont work. Form 2 is my appointment planner form, when clicking on save on this form it will add a new object to the list, so a new picturebox should be created. I have checked the debug using breakpoints, and strange enough it will go through the create code, but no matter what I do it wont render the pictureboxxes.

I personally think it has to do with the form1 not Initializing when called from form2.closed event. But even when using InitializeComponent(); end Refresh(); inside my code it still doesnt work.

Am I using the wrong event or is there a specific call I need to make to generate the pictureboxxes?

Sorry if my post is lacking code or info, I'm not used to posting on stackoverflow, feel free to ask for more information if needed.

Answer (score 0):

if you run your code from Form2 and you want to add control to Form1 you cannot use "this". Form1 has to be accessible from Form2.

```
PictureBox Point = new PictureBox();    
Point.Location = new Point(obj.Location.X, 45 + obj.Location.Y);    
Point.BackColor = color;
Point.Size = new Size(96, 25);
Point.Enabled = false;
Point.Tag = "Point";
Point.TabIndex = 100;
Point.Visible = true;
Form1.Controls.Add(Point);
```

Comment: Hi Wojciech, the constructor code for the picturebox is within the form1 class, when starting form2 I'm adding form2.closed as a eventhandler, so the form2.closed event is also in the form1 class. I choose for this option because working with static was not a option and initializing the form1 would reset multiable variables.

Comment: Could you pass more codes?

Comment: Here is about all the code what had to do with the generation. In this first code I'm starting a new Form page, named dayview. dayview is my form2 and agendamain is my form1. ```
            AgendaMain agendamain = new AgendaMain();
            DayView dayview = new DayView();
            dayview.FormClosed += agendamain.Closed;
            dayview.ShowDialog(); ``` My Closed event is only calling Agendamaker(), the method which should create the picture boxxes See the full method here [link] https://justpaste.it/2blv4  See the link for more expla. Sorry for the inconvenience, char limit.